# How to use the word 'int', but as a string and not a data type in C?

Tags: c, string

I am checking input and need a way to compare to the actual word 'int'.

Example:

```
char t[10] = "int";
if (t == 'int'){
   printf("We have an integr");
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, still learning the ropes of C. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please spend a *little*  more time learning on your own before posting on this site, or at least make a minimal effort to research "string comparison in C" on your own.

Comment: Also don't compare strings with `==`. You should probably read some more tutorial.

Comment: @TomSwifty, using double quotes doesn't work either.

Comment: you should've atleast googled `how to compare strings in C`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare the text.  Note that it returns a zero on a match:

```
if (strcmp(t, "int") == 0) {
     printf("We have an integer\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `char t[]="int";` includes the null terminator for using with `strcmp()`, while not using unecessary memory while providing the string version of `int` you are looking for.

***Note:*** Using the `==` operator will not work for a string comparison unless you check each char element, one at a time. (see *second* example below)

```
char t[] = {"int"};
if (strcmp(t, "int")==0){
   printf("We have an integr");
}
```

Using `==`:

```
if((t[0]=='i')&&(t[1]=='n')&&(t[2]=='t')&&(t[3]=='\0')){...
```

would also work

Answer (score 0):

`"int"` is a string literal. It has *nothing* to do with the `int` type or any value of said type. The exact same problem exists if using `"foobar"` with the original code. A string is a string.

Using `'int'` (or `'foobar'`) is also wrong, because those are [confusing] character literals (of type `char`) and not string literals (of type `char*`). The compiler should have generated a warning or two - *enable and read all warnings!* - even though it compiled.

And finally, see the other answers for how to correctly compare strings in C which explain why the `==` approach doesn't work.